# QGIS - Export PDF map with georeferenced data

Tags: qgis, export, geospatial-pdf

I am used to working with ArcMap but have been playing around with QGIS.
When I export a PDF map with ArcMap, the PDF is spatially referenced. This is a handy tool, I can put the PDF map on my iPhone and it tracks my location on the map (even when I'm out in the woods away from cell coverage). It's very handy for forestry work.

Are the PDF maps exported with QGIS also spatially referenced? Is there a plugin that allows for this feature?

Comment: Wow.  What app can do that? Android have an equivalent? The GIS software I use, including ArcMap, can't use pdfs in that way as far as I know.

Comment: @johns: TerraGo for instance. Have a look at the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geospatial_PDF#Applications_reading_geospatial_PDFs

Comment: I use the app "Avenza PDF maps". It's available for both iphone and android. Just make sure your phone has actual GPS and doesn't just rely on phone signal.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a plugin.  QGIS uses GDAL/OGR and if your version of QGIS uses a GDAL/OGR version that can read and write geospatial PDF ([Geospatial PDF](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html))

[image]

no problem.